# App Transport Security blocks routing via custom url scheme

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, url-scheme

My iOS app (written in Swift and React Native) has a custom url scheme that allows me to route to the app from e.g. Safari like this [myappscheme://https://www.mywebsite.com/somematerial](http://myappscheme://https://www.mywebsite.com/somematerial). If I enable App Transport Security in my app, the routing via custom url scheme is blocked and I get this message:

> App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource
>   load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via
>   your app's Info.plist file.

However, if I disable ATS, the app routes as expected. I am not accessing any link via http in my app and in my routing I always fetch data via https. Therefore, I don't know why ATS is blocking this routing. Do you know if I have to provide some additional info about my url scheme?

Please see my ATS configurations in Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

I've also whitelisted my custom url scheme:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>myappscheme</string>
</array>
```

Comment: instead of 'localhost' try 'server.local'

Comment: @Floler thanks for the suggestion but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. I logged out the endpoint I was hitting and checked if it satisfied ATS requirements by doing in Terminal:

```
nscurl --ats-diagnostics https://www.example.com/
```

It turned out that the particular subdomain I was trying to fetch failed all ATS requirements. My server team has fixed the issue and made the endpoint secure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with React Native, you mentioned that you use Safari as a source for custom links and probably it means that you're trying to debug your app & custom routing in Simulator, so maybe your issue related to React Native. If you have the same behaviour on a real device when React Native works offline, then please update your question.

> Temporarily disable App Transport Security (ATS) by adding the
>   `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` entry to your `Info.plist` file. Since ATS does
>   not allow insecure HTTP requests to IP addresses, you must completely
>   disable it to run on a device. This is only a requirement for
>   development on a device, and unless you can't workaround an issue you
>   should leave ATS enabled for production builds. For more information,
>   see [this post](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/) on configuring ATS.

[React Native Documentation - Running On Device](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.28/docs/running-on-device-ios.html)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this is not the case. I also have an older version of my app in Swift only and the routing via custom url scheme does also not work there if I do not allow arbitrary loads. I'm not debugging through Safari, I'm opening the url from my swift code with UIApplication.shared.openURL(myappscheme://mywebsite.com/som‌​ematerial). I have the same issue on simulator and device.

Answer (score 0):

Configure `info.plist` setting.

You can add a specific domain like:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>www.google.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.1</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want to list my domain as an exception. I want to satisfy the ATS requirements.